# After Response.redirect Onselectedindexchanged keeps firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form I am building to bring up reports from Srss using response.redirect().  After this though whenever another postback happens the same onselectedindexchanged events keep firing.  Is there something that needs to happen to clear the event?

For example, when the ddlBlankForms index changes, the event fires and the response.redirect makes the file download.  But the drop down list does not return to index 0 like the code suggests.  And now after any more events like for example one of the other drop down lists, the ddlBlankForms_OnSelectedIndexChanged keeps trying to fire.  If I remove the response.redirect it seems to work but it defeats the purpose which is to open the file.

Code Behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        ddlBusinessUnit.DataSource = sqlCommands.GetBusinessUnits();
        ddlBusinessUnit.DataValueField = "BusinessUnit";
        ddlBusinessUnit.DataBind();
        ddlBusinessUnit.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));

        ddlBlankForms.DataSource = sqlCommands.GetForms();
        ddlBlankForms.DataTextField = "FormDesc";
        ddlBlankForms.DataValueField = "FormReport";
        ddlBlankForms.DataBind();
        ddlBlankForms.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
    }
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //ddlBusinessUnit.DataSource = sqlCommands.GetBusinessUnits();
    //ddlBusinessUnit.DataValueField = "BusinessUnit";
    //ddlBusinessUnit.DataBind();
    //ddlBusinessUnit.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));

    //ddlBlankForms.DataSource = sqlCommands.GetForms();
    //ddlBlankForms.DataTextField = "FormDesc";
    //ddlBlankForms.DataValueField = "FormReport";
    //ddlBlankForms.DataBind();
    //ddlBlankForms.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
}

protected void ddlBusinessUnit_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlType.DataSource = sqlCommands.GetTypes(ddlBusinessUnit.SelectedValue);
    ddlType.DataValueField = "FormID";
    ddlType.DataTextField = "TypeDesc";
    ddlType.DataBind();
    ddlType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "")); 
}

protected void ddlType_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlTask.DataSource = sqlCommands.GetTasks(ddlType.SelectedValue, ddlBusinessUnit.SelectedValue);
    ddlTask.DataValueField = "TaskID";
    ddlTask.DataBind();
    ddlTask.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "")); 
}

protected void ddlTask_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlTask.SelectedIndex == 0) return;
    string url = "http://reportserver";
    url += sqlCommands.GetSpecificFormReportName(ddlType.SelectedValue);
    url += "&BU=" + ddlBusinessUnit.SelectedValue;
    url += "&TID=" + ddlTask.SelectedValue;
    url += "&rs:Format=PDF";
    Response.Redirect(url);


    //Response.Redirect("http://mje-imtmisql03/reportserver?/QAQC_Reports/QCBore&BU=251Template&TID=Required1&rs:Format=PDF");
}

protected void ddlBlankForms_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlBlankForms.SelectedIndex == 0) return;
    string url = "http://reportserver";
    url += ddlBlankForms.SelectedValue;
    url += "&BU=";
    url += "&TID=";
    url += "&rs:Format=PDF";
    ddlBlankForms.SelectedIndex = 0;
    Response.Redirect(url);
    //Response.End();
}
```

ASP.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlBlankForms" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBlankForms_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" Width="300px"/>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTask" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTask_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="True" Width="200px"/>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlType" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlType_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="True" Width="200px"/>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBusinessUnit_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="true" ID="ddlBusinessUnit" Width="200px"/>
```

Comment: Could you show your `Page_load` method?

Comment: @lnanikian I have nothing on load, just on the page_init, I have added this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the `Page_Load`  `event` :**When this event fires, the page and its controls are fully initialized, and their previous values are restored.** Use also the `IsPostBack` `property` aslo.
But for the `Page_Init` `event`:The framework uses this event to set the properties of web controls to their previous values via postback or view state data.

So you can try this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      If(!IsPostBack)
       {
        ddlBusinessUnit.DataSource = sqlCommands.GetBusinessUnits();
        ddlBusinessUnit.DataValueField = "BusinessUnit";
        ddlBusinessUnit.DataBind();
        ddlBusinessUnit.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));

        ddlBlankForms.DataSource = sqlCommands.GetForms();
        ddlBlankForms.DataTextField = "FormDesc";
        ddlBlankForms.DataValueField = "FormReport";
        ddlBlankForms.DataBind();
        ddlBlankForms.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
      }
    }
```

And leave the `Page_Init` empty

```
     the protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //empty   
    }
```

I hope it will help you. It is just a solution between many.

### Update

```
  protected void ddlTask_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (ddlTask.SelectedIndex == 0) return;
   string url = "http://reportserver";
   url += sqlCommands.GetSpecificFormReportName(ddlType.SelectedValue);
   url += "&BU=" + ddlBusinessUnit.SelectedValue;
   url += "&TID=" + ddlTask.SelectedValue;
   url += "&rs:Format=PDF";
   Response.Redirect(url, false);//false to allow the code to continue execution
   Return;
 }
```

Comment: it really didn't solve the issue though.  For example, I have a similar code behind for ddlBusinessUnit.  Lets say that I drop down ddlBlankForms and it's event fires, the response.redirect fired off the pdf download, but the dropdown list does not return to index 0 like the code suggests it should.  So the next time I trigger another event like the index change of ddlBusinessUnit, the event of ddlBlankforms fires again.  It's like redirecting the response means that the previous code doesn't happen and it keeps trying to do it again.

Comment: What if you remove thé `Response.End()`

Comment: @Inanikian Nothing, that was just a remnant of trying some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

did you try following ?

```
Response.Redirect(url, false);
```

Comment: put it in both places, but it doesn't seem to effect anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have a "partial" fix for this. It's not 100%, and should be considered a "hack".

Basically the page has to render in the browser in order for the `ViewState` to contain the "cleared" drop down list.

```
public class ResponseStuff
{
    public static void ClientRedirect(Page page,string url)
    {
        string script = "<script type='text/javascript' runat='client'>$(function() {window.location='" + page.ResolveUrl(url) + "';});</script>";
        page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("client_redirect",script);
    }
}
```

called via

```
ddl.ClearSelection();
ResponseStuff.ClientRedirect(this,url);
```

hack alert caveats: Hitting the browser back button twice (fast) causes the same behavior before this fix. When the back button is clicked, a redirect is again performed, however the drop down is "cleared". This requires JQuery.